# Git made 3 Gits And Now Not Working At All

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, branch

**Help!**

I implemented Git to my project and somehow Git has made 3 files for saving my information: (1) Saves all of my view controllers, (2) The same file as (1), (3) my pods only.

The one containing my pods seems to be broken as I can not commit anything to it. First I thought nothing of these 3 Gits and proceeded coding, but now I am trying to branch my master with something I have been spending months coding but it seems to be crashing every time because it does not save my code to the master and makes me update my pods. Now after I tried to branch it, it did not work but now when I try to commit my files to the current branch I'm working on, it is not letting me without committing all 1600 files that are in my Pods. But the Pod file will not commit! I have no clue how to fix this and I am in desperate need of help!!!! Can anyone please help. I just want to have one place that will commit my files like in every Xcode git file. I do not want to lose my months of work.

I get the error: "The working copy “Pods” failed to commit files. - The source control operation failed because no repository could be found."

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Please trouble shooting you issue with below aspects:

#### 1.   Use one git repository

- If you mean 3 gits are **3 git repositories**, you should keep only one git repo to manage your project. Only keep the repo that can contain all the files you want to manage under it’s directory.

  As below example, if you project (the files you want to manage in git repo) is under `Dir2` (not contains it’s parent `Dir1`), then you should remove the other two repos for `Dir1` and `Dir3` by removing the folders `Dir1/.git` and `Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/.git`.

  ```
  Dir1
   |___.git
   |___ …
   |___Dir2
        |___.git
        |___ …
        |___Dir3
             |___.git
             |___ …
  ```
- If you mean 3 gits are **3 git branches** for the same git repo, before switching branches, you should make sure the work directory is clean (save and commit changes before switching branches).

#### 2.   Mark sure `user.name` and `user.email` has already been set

You can use the command `git config -l` to check if the output contains:

```
user.name=<username>
user.email=<email address>
```

If the output does not contain `user.name` and `user.email`, you should set as below:

```
git config --global user.name yourname
git config --global user.email xxx@xx.com
```

Comment: Hi I am new to Git and not sure how to access get to where your step 1 is pointed at (Dir1/2/3)? How to I see these files?

Comment: You can go to the directory where you want to manage the files in git repo, and use the command `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. If it list the same directory as you need, that means no git repos in the parent folder. Besides, did you check the step 2?

Comment: So I have the first problem you suggested "(the files you want to manage in git repo) is under `Dir2`". I used the command to `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to see the files I want to manage is under it's parent folder but when I use the command `myParentFolder/.git` to get rid of the git, I receive the error: "myParentFolder/.git: No such file or directory". How do I fix this?

Comment: And yes I did do step 2